# Power of a number tail recursion

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, tail-recursion

I am trying to calculate power of a num using tail recursion with a running time of log(n). From what I understand, the difference between using power // 2 instead of power - 1 is to reduce the running time. Thus when I calculate the value, I need to multiply the old value with two other sum instead of just one. My code works find until it reaches power_of(2,6)

```
def power_of(num,power,value = 1):
    if power == 0:
        return 1

    elif power == 1:
        return value

    elif power % 2 != 0:
        return power_of(num, power // 2 , value * num * num * num)

    else:
        return power_of(num, power // 2 , value * num * num)

power_of(2,6)
```

Comment: Your code is all wrong. Check power_of(2,1).

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/mvasilkov/1379824

Answer (score 1):

Ok tail recursion, right. I am sorry about the other answer. Your method should work, just a couple modifications need to be made. For the evens, you want to replace num with num * num, and keep value as value. For the odds, you want to replace num with num * num, make value * num the value, and subtract 1 before you divide the power.

```
def power_of(num,power, value = 1):

    if power == 0:
      return value

    if power == 1:
        return value * num

    elif power % 2 != 0:
        return power_of(num*num, (power - 1) // 2, value * num)

    else:
        return power_of(num*num, power // 2, value)

print(power_of(2,6))
```

I pretty much copied with from this from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

Comment: of course wikipedia has a more efficient approach, I was hoping he'd figure it out from where I left it..

Comment: What's the purpose of the extra 'power == 1' base case?

Answer (score 0):

https://repl.it/repls/WiltedOrnateMetadata

The main issue is you are under-multiplying your tail value. Say power=9, power // 2 = 4, power - power // 2 = 5, and you are only going to multiply value * num ^ 3. Let me know if this doesn't make sense.

Also, you have an issue with power == 1, gotta return num if value is 1.

```
def power_of(num,power,value = 1):
    print ("power_of({},{},{})".format(num,power,value)) # this was how I debugged it
    if power == 0:
        return 1

    elif power == 1:
        return num if value == 1 else value

    elif power % 2 != 0:
        for a in range(1, power - power // 2):
          value *= num
        return power_of(num, power // 2 , value)

    else:
        for a in range(1, power - power // 2):
          value *= num
        return power_of(num, power // 2 , value * num * num)
```

Output:

```
print(power_of(2,9))
power_of(2,9,1)
power_of(2,4,16)
power_of(2,2,128)
power_of(2,1,512)
512
```

Answer (score 0):

See how this works:

```
from hypothesis import given, strategies as st, settings, example

def power_of(num,power):
    if power == 0:
        return 1
    elif power == 1:
        return num
    elif power % 2 != 0:
        return num * power_of(num*num, power // 2)
    else:
        return power_of(num*num, power // 2)

@given(st.integers(min_value=0), st.integers(min_value=0))
@example(2, 6)
def test_power_of(i, j):
    assert power_of(i, j) == i**j
```

Comment: This is not tail recursion

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function is called Tail Recursive iff the recursive is the last statement to be executed in a recursive function. In the case of calculating `x` raised to the power of `n (x^n)`, a normal recursive function may store all the values in the Stack till it reaches `n == 1` or `n == 0` (as per your base condition) whereas we don't want to use all those states/instances. So what we can do is keep saving the latest states in a variable and return that variable as soon as we reach our base case.

```
    int x = scanner.nextInt(); 
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    int res = printPower(x, n);
    int resTail =  printPowerTail (x, n, x);   
    System.out.println(res);     
    System.out.println(resTail);

static int printPower (int x, int n) {
    if (n == 1) 
        return x;
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    return x * printPower(x, n - 1); // this call will store all the instances of n till n == 1
}
static int printPowerTail (int x, int n, int flag) {
    if (n == 1) 
        return flag;
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    return printPowerTail(x, n - 1, flag * x);
}
```

Comment: Why is your recursive function named `printX` when it's actually pure?